# React Native on device causes "Unhandled JS Exception: new.target"

Tags: react-native

Hoping this is a simple issue but I couldn't find anything on a Google search. Running on emulator (with any build type) works perfectly. Connecting a device however with any build type (debug or release) the following issue occurs at runtime (the app can build successfully):

[image]

My `package.json` has the following deps:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@redux-offline/redux-offline": "2.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "6.9.4",
    "buffer": "5.2.0",
    "crypto-js": "3.1.9-1",
    "lodash": "4.17.10",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.54.4",
    "react-native-fast-image": "4.0.14",
    "react-native-firebase": "4.3.8",
    "react-native-fs": "2.10.14",
    "react-native-maps": "0.21.0",
    "react-native-maps-super-cluster": "1.4.1",
    "react-native-navigation": "1.1.471",
    "react-native-svg": "6.4.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "1.0.2",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "whatwg-url": "6.5.0"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "23.0.1",
    "babel-preset-flow": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.49.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.9.1",
    "flow-bin": "0.65.0",
    "husky": "0.14.3",
    "jest": "23.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "7.1.3",
    "prettier": "1.13.4",
    "react-native-schemes-manager": "1.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.1"
  },
```

My `.babelrc` has the following:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native", "flow"],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
}
```

I am using `react-native-schemes-manager` to build a flavour of base app. The config for this is in the `package.json` like so:

```
"xcodeSchemes": {
  "Debug": [
    "FakeAppNameDebug"
  ],
  "Release": [
    "FakeAppNameRelease"
  ]
}
```

None of this explains how it works perfectly fine on a simulator but wants to throw tantrums when running on a device though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, that's what I've found out:

JS in RN [is executed in two different environments (V8 or JavaScriptCore)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment#javascript-runtime), depending on how you run it. E.g. in my case the app worked properly on iOS simulator with and without remote js debugger; on Android simulator worked only with remote debugger turned on and threw the error without it; on a real Android device threw the error. Taking into consideration that [JSC comes in two different versions (supplied by iOS or packaged in RN app for Android)](https://www.reactnative.guide/3-react-native-internals/3.1-react-native-internals.html), I concluded that the iOS JSC and V8 *do* understand `target.new`, whilst the Android-packaged JSC doesn't (btw neither does Babel).

That's the reason why `new.target` fails, depending on where you run it.

Now where this bug comes from: I used [this method](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19350#issuecomment-419899047) to find the culrpit and located it in the `whatwg-url` package, in `node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/URL.js`:

```
return iface.setup(Object.create(new.target.prototype), args);
```

---

tl;dr; There are several possible solutions:

- Get rid of `whatwg-url`. This may be just a temporary solution, because there are more things that the original JSC doesn't support (e.g. proxies or symbols that can't be simply transpiled or polyfilled).
- Replace JSC with an alternative. The 2 options I've found are: [jsc-android-buildscripts](https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts) (an RN go-to solution, so probably a better option) and [LiquidCore](https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore). This can be a good investment since the original JSC hasn't been developed since 2016 (:sick:).
- Wait for RN v0.59, which will replace the JSC.
- *Bonus:* You can try changing the `new.target` occurrences to `new . target` (which apparently is supported in all the engines) just to check if `newTarget` is the only problem you have. In my case, it appeared that it's also proxies that aren't supported (I'm using mobx v5), so just getting rid of `whatwg-url` wouldn't solve my problem.